# Implementing SSO between webapplications on different servers without changes on existing applications

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on

We have already created 2 JAVA web applications A & B and hosted it on 2 different
servers using TOMCAT on both these servers. These applications have already been moved 
to production and we cannot make any major changes or move it to a single server as it is not in our control.

The authentication is being done through a common LDAP server which is being used by many other applications also.

Now, the client wants us to create a new application C and once logged in, the end users should be able to access the above 2 Applications A & B(through links) without having to
re-login again(SSO).

Pls advise on how to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

CAS seems the right solution for this but I don't see how you could do to avoid touching anything.

You will at least have to touch some config files.
Look at:
- [Spring Security and CAS Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834710/spring-security-and-cas-integration)

Regards