# Implementing SSO for web application hosted on different servers

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have web applications hosted on different servers (eg WebApp1 on Tomcat server , Web App2 on Jbossserver). I need to implement single-sign-on for this applications . Please suggest me on how to proceed on this with different framework in place , some applications are built on spring framework and some on Jsp/Servlets .Whether i can take advantages on this framework and can implement SSO . Its a extention to this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003451/implementing-sso-between-webapplications-on-different-servers-without-changes-on) .

Answer (score 2):

If the directory service implementation is Microsoft Active directory, then it's better to go with Kerberos. Spring Security support Kerberos via spring-security extension project. Have a look at [spring security kerberos](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-kerberos-introduction)  project.

For other LDAP implementations (apache DS, Open DS), spring+JASIG-CAS will suit your requirement.  [read more](http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.ae/2012/03/single-sign-on-using-cas-spring-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Spring, I'd suggest using [SpringSecurity](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) with [JA-SIG's Central Authentication Service (CAS)](http://www.jasig.org/cas). The Spring security docs provide details of [how to set this up](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html).

I used this myself on a couple of projects and it has worked perfectly.